# Can't make AWUS036H work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, drivers, alfa-wireless

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10. 
This is my kernel version:

> Linux 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:48:01 UTC
>   2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My wireless card is an AWUSU36H

[image]

The first thing I do to install the driver is copy the driver from the CD to the Downloads folder.

```
cd /media/me/AWUS036H/Drivers/RTL8187L/Unix (Linux)/Linux driver for kernel 2.6.X$ 
cp rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007.tar.gz ~/Downloads/
```

Then I extract the tar

```
tar xvfz rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007.tar.gz
```

I navigate into the extracted folder, and I try to follow the instructions in the Readme.txt

```
cd rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007
```

This are the contents of the folder:

```
drv.tar.gz   makedrv     stack.tar.gz  wlan0rmv
ieee80211    ReadMe.txt  wlan0dhcp     wlan0up
ifcfg-wlan0  rtl8187     wlan0down     wpa_supplicant-0.4.9
```

This is what the Readme.txt says:

```
Release Date: 2006-02-09, ver 1.2^M
RTL8187 Linux driver version 1.2^M
^M
   --This driver supports RealTek RTL8187 Wireless LAN driver for ^M
     Fedora Core 2/3/4/5, Debian 3.1, Mandrake 10.2/Mandriva 2006, ^M
     SUSE 9.3/10.1/10.2, Gentoo 3.1, etc.^M
   - Support Client mode for either infrastructure or adhoc mode^M
   - Support WEP and WPAPSK connection^M
^M
< Component >^M
The driver is composed of several parts:^M
        1. Module source code^M
          stack.tar.gz^M
          drv.tar.gz^M
        ^M
        2. Script ot build the modules^M
          makedrv^M
^M
        3. Script to load/unload modules^M
          wlan0up^M
          wlan0down ^M
^M
        4. Script and configuration for DHCP^M
"ReadMe.txt" [readonly] 140 lines, 4590 characters
```

So what I do know is extract both of the compressed files:

```
sudo tar xvfz drv.tar.gz
sudo tar xvfz stack.tar.gz
```

This 2 commands will add some data to the folders **ieee80211** and **rtl8187**

At this point I get lost, and I don't know what to do.
If I go in each of this 2 folders and I run the ***sudo make*** command then I get errors like this one:

```
 sudo makemake -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/build M=/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.o
In file included from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:64:0:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187.h:29:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

If I try to run any of the script **./makedrv** that the instructions describe, then I also get an error:

```
 ~/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007$ sudo ./makedrv 
[sudo] password for me: 
ieee80211/
ieee80211/license
ieee80211/ieee80211_crypt.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_tx.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac_wx.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_module.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_crypt_ccmp.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_rx.c
ieee80211/tags
ieee80211/ieee80211_crypt_tkip.c
ieee80211/Makefile
ieee80211/readme
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/ieee80211-rtl.mod
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/ieee80211_crypt_wep-rtl.mod
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/ieee80211_crypt_tkip-rtl.mod
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/ieee80211_crypt-rtl.mod
ieee80211/.tmp_versions/ieee80211_crypt_ccmp-rtl.mod
ieee80211/ieee80211_crypt_wep.c
ieee80211/ieee80211.h
ieee80211/ieee80211_wx.c
ieee80211/ieee80211_crypt.h
rtl8187/
rtl8187/license
rtl8187/r8180_rtl8225z2.c
rtl8187/r8180_rtl8225.h
rtl8187/r8187_led.c
rtl8187/r8180_93cx6.h
rtl8187/r8180_wx.h
rtl8187/r8180_hw.h
rtl8187/copying
rtl8187/r8187_led.h
rtl8187/r8180_pm.h
rtl8187/tags
rtl8187/r8187.h
rtl8187/Makefile
rtl8187/r8180_rtl8225.c
rtl8187/readme
rtl8187/install
rtl8187/.tmp_versions/
rtl8187/.tmp_versions/r8187.mod
rtl8187/changes
rtl8187/r8180_wx.c
rtl8187/r8180_pm.c
rtl8187/r8187_core.c
rtl8187/r8180_93cx6.c
rtl8187/authors
rtl8187/ieee80211.h
rtl8187/ieee80211_crypt.h
rm -f *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -rf /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/tmp
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/build M=/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.o
In file included from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:0:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:1019:24: error: field ‘ps_task’ has incomplete type
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_softmac_scan_wq’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:421:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘queue_delayed_work’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/srcu.h:32:0,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/uprobes.h:26,
                 from include/linux/uprobes.h:35,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:15,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:134,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:26,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:
include/linux/workqueue.h:371:12: note: expected ‘struct delayed_work *’ but argument is of type ‘struct work_struct *’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_softmac_stop_scan’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:495:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cancel_delayed_work’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/srcu.h:32:0,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/uprobes.h:26,
                 from include/linux/uprobes.h:35,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:15,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:134,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:26,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:
include/linux/workqueue.h:410:20: note: expected ‘struct delayed_work *’ but argument is of type ‘struct work_struct *’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_associate_abort’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:915:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘queue_delayed_work’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/srcu.h:32:0,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/uprobes.h:26,
                 from include/linux/uprobes.h:35,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:15,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:134,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:26,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:
include/linux/workqueue.h:371:12: note: expected ‘struct delayed_work *’ but argument is of type ‘struct work_struct *’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_rx_frame_softmac’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:1527:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘tasklet_schedule’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_stop_protocol_rtl’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2120:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cancel_delayed_work’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/srcu.h:32:0,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/uprobes.h:26,
                 from include/linux/uprobes.h:35,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:15,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:134,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:26,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:
include/linux/workqueue.h:410:20: note: expected ‘struct delayed_work *’ but argument is of type ‘struct work_struct *’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_softmac_init’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2229:78: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2229:2: error: ‘INIT_WORK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2229:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2230:88: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2231:94: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2232:96: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2233:82: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2234:82: error: macro "INIT_WORK" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2244:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘tasklet_init’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_softmac_free’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2255:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cancel_delayed_work’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from include/linux/srcu.h:32:0,
                 from include/linux/notifier.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/uprobes.h:26,
                 from include/linux/uprobes.h:35,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:15,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/if_ether.h:134,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:26,
                 from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:
include/linux/workqueue.h:410:20: note: expected ‘struct delayed_work *’ but argument is of type ‘struct work_struct *’
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: In function ‘ieee80211_wpa_set_encryption’:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2489:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘request_module’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2518:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘try_module_get’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c: At top level:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2663:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2663:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2663:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2664:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2664:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2664:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2665:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2665:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2665:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2666:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2666:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2666:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2667:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2667:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2667:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2668:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2668:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2668:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2669:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2669:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2669:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2670:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2670:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2670:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2671:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2671:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2671:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2672:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2672:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2672:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2673:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2673:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2673:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2674:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2674:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_SYMBOL’ [-Wimplicit-int]
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:2674:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]
In file included from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.c:17:0:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211.h:1212:37: warning: ‘netdev_priv’ is static but used in inline function ‘ieee80211_priv’ which is not static [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211/ieee80211_softmac.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/ieee80211] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
rm -f *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -rf /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/tmp
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-19-generic/build M=/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.o
In file included from /home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.c:64:0:
/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187.h:29:26: fatal error: linux/config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187/r8187_core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/me/Downloads/rtl8187_linux_26.1025.0328.2007/rtl8187] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Can somebody give me a hand finding out what I need to do to make my wifi card work?

**Update**

This is the output of the lsusb command

```
   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 147e:1000 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

It looks like the adapter is recognized.
Also I noticed that if i use the command ifconfig I see this:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.19  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxx::xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25091 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12342 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15630234 (15.6 MB)  TX bytes:3054709 (3.0 MB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

It looks like the computer sees the card but only if I turn on the button in the laptop that enables the internal network card. If it is of, then wlan1(which is my AWUSU36H) is not visible. If the button is of, then computer doesn't detect that card.

Still don't know how to make the card work. I only want the AWUSU36H to work but not the integrated one.

This is the outut of the command **sudo lshw -C network**:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.5.0-19-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:21:85:dc:36:27
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febff000-febfffff memory:f7ff0000-f7ffffff memory:febc0000-febdffff
```

Comment: We need a bit more information. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsusb. I believe rtl8187 is included in 12.10 and I'd be very surprised if your device isn't already covered. I would be more surprised if you could get this antique to build on your shiny new 12.10 kernel.

Comment: @chili555 Just updated the question. I am not very experienced with  linux, do you think my hardware is incompatible with the OS? Is there some driver that can make it work?

Comment: I doubt it is incompatible at all. In order to see the device in lsusb, it kind of needs to be plugged in. Please try again.

Comment: @chili555 Just updated, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use the USB instead of the internal device, I suggest you blacklist the driver for the internal device. That will allow you to keep the switch on and use the USB. It has a working driver, rtl8187 and has created an interface wlan1.

Find out the driver for the internal with:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Find the part that refers to 'driver=' associated with wlan0, the internal. Then blacklist it:

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist <some_driver>" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Plug in the USB, reboot and it should be working. If in doubt about the correct driver to blacklist, post your findings and we'll help.

Comment: I just added the output of tye command `lshw`. 
But I am confused, I don't really want to blacklist the internal card. When I am close to the router I like using the internal card but when I am far I prefer to use the external antena. Is that possible?

Comment: The driver for your internal, rt2800pci is a bit twitchy and I have no doubt it's not working well at any distance. You might simply unload the internal driver with sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci. Reload with sudo modprobe rt2800pci. You might also try to troubleshoot the internal and, of course, simply use the USB exclusively. I fear Network Manager is working against you here.

Comment: This is what I did. I unloaded the driver using the comand ` sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci` Now it is wlan1 the only wifi adapter that appears when I type `ifconfig`. So the problem is solved now I can use the external adapter.That was it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You still need a **blacklist** entry, to make this fix more permanent.