# Problems installing AWUS036H adapter in Ubuntu 12.10, Can connnect but no data transfer

Tags: 12.10, usb, realtek, alfa-wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t make AWUS036H work in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229678/cant-make-awus036h-work-in-ubuntu-12-10)

Any help would be really appreciated, problem is I finally got my brand new AWUS036H wireless USB dongle for X-mas and was so excited but so far I have been let down.

I done a pretty good amount of research before choosing the device I chose because it was supposed to work out of the box with Linux so I didn't get the newer versions of the *Alfa* (brand) WiFi adapter.

I'm running Ubuntu **12.10** and the adapter has a *Realtek* chipset. At first I could get it to connect and transfer but then the next day it would only connect, show many networks available (with good signals) and will connect - but when trying to surf it won't even load a web page.

Even though I hated to, I thought I would see what it would do in *argh* WINDOWS. So I got a old laptop out and loaded up Windows 7, Installed the drivers it came with without moving the adapter from where it was before - so I would have a control test. It connected and was able to surf the internet like the signal strength suggested it would - [it] was pretty darn fast.

*So just cant understand why it will work that well under WINDOWS and wont **with me** in Ubuntu 12.10 ..*

I know that others have it working flawlessly, [so] if anyone out there can hold my hand a bit and help me get this fixed I would really appreciate it (*I refuse to install Windows.*). Thanks in advance.